# Large dataset from server to clients browser

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5, eloquent

The idea is about big datasets queried from MySQL and sending it to a lot of clients. Secondly, after a give this date to the client and render it in a browser, people can edit the price of all these rows and depends on the price, the position in the list will change. So if client 1 update price all clients should get this price and the position of all clients should change at the same time. So I need to rebuild UI for every client I have.

So actually, at this moment, I am trying to understand from what should I start. Firstly I think, to use local storage of clients browser, but it has a 5MB limit.

Also, I understand that I can't send over 50k rows from db via web sockets, because web sockets build for short and fast messages, but not for big data. So help me with my question, what should I use and what should I learn to make fast, real-time updating data from db to browser? 
I think, that I need to save all date somewhere on the client side, and then after updates, get just items that have been updated, send it to client, and update data on client side,and only then I going to show it's to all clients at the same time, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the data through an endpoint which returns json and render that. Then using websocket, you can send a message to all connected clients to refetch the data from that endpoint if a change has been made. Also, I would highly recommend using pagination for large datasets.

Comment: I need to find more information about what is endpoints, cause my English is so bad... Anyway, thank you, and I can't use pagination, because all user should see their position in list. And Its a little bit complicated list. The idea is that I have to show all users the products in which they compete with other users. By this I can not break the query in the database into parts. Since the same user can be at the top of the list with item 1 and at the end with item 16

Here is example, how will it looks like [https://i.ibb.co/3Rz7xDW/Screenshot-from-2019-05-17-22-06-58.png]

Comment: An endpoint is the url that will return the data (ie: `http://api.com/endpoint`). It can be used by any client to get json data using AJAX. That way when the client loads the page it will load the data and connect to your websocket server. If the websocket server returns a message like refetch data then it will just make another ajax request to the endpoint and replace what is already stored. You should use React or another front-end library to create the page so you don't have to replace what is in the DOM manually.

Comment: But if I want to replace new data, I need to save previous data some where, right? 
And also is it possible to sort all this data fast, than sort and group it on server and send fast to client as partial view?

Comment: I think it's not a simple job to explain here. You will need to setup a database like MySQL to store the data. Clients should not need to store the data, they will fetch it from the backend server. If you make an update, you will update the backend database.

Comment: So the only one way is to setup my db server and get as more server power as I can, right? May be, you can give a few advices about what should I google and what should I learn and how to optimize so big query. I think, I can use memcache to save and get all this data fast, is it good idea?

Comment: Yes, I think 50k rows in a mysql database is not alot. You should be able to handle it without any problem. Also if you do use a database, then I don't see any issues with pagination since it would be built into the database. For example with MySQL you can query your database with a limit and offset to get only a certain portion of the data and also sort them so it stays the same for all clients. You should read more about full stack web development, as this is big task.

Comment: Yeap, 50k rows it's not a big deal, but when we speak 50k rows for 500 user at the same time, it's a bit harder)

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The 50k rows in the database will be the same for all users. They would all read the same 50k rows and when you update a row, they would just refetch those 50k rows again. Reading all the data is very fast, but the problem will become when transferring all that data to the client which depends on network connection, latency and bandwidth. However, if you have pagination then they can just fetch only 50 rows.

Comment: But if I use pagination, I can't group all user who set price for specific product. Because some of them can be out of first or second query

Comment: Maybe you can first try setting up a database and getting it working with that. If then you come into performance issues then maybe figure out a way to add pagination.